# How do I modify the code in this extension to run the export function via cron after each order

Tags: magento, csv, cron, export

I am currently using the Bulk Import+Export Orders to CSV extension that is available at:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

The main function that I need is the export orders function, which is working fine. As this lets me import my magento orders into the order processing system which is being used for shipping out the products.

What I am trying to achieve is having the export function run automatically, preferably after every order is received. If not at least at certain times of the day.

I have looked around can't seem to find the information on what i need to look for to modify this to allow the cron functionality. The csv file that is generated is perfect for my processing system, order extensions do not format the files as i need.

I'm not the most experience, but am learning as I go along. Please can someone point me to where i need to look to allow the export function to available via a cron job.

All the advice is appreciated, the website is running on magento 1.9.2.2.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an observer that fires after each order placed or a cronjob that fires once/twice/on schedule daily.

Observer after each order:

edit:

```
app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Exporter/etc/config.xml
```

Add:

```
<!-- Add to global tag for frontend/backend orders -->
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <!-- Can be named anything so long as it doesn't clash so make it specific -->
            <namespace_export_orders_after_each_order>
                <class>Raveninfosys_Exporter_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>exportOrders</method>
            </namespace_export_orders_after_each_order>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Then create the observer that calls the export order function:

```
app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Exporter/Model/Observer.php

<?php
    class Raveinfosys_Exporter_Model_Observer
    {
        public function exportOrders( Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver ) 
        {
            $oOrder = $oObserver->getEvent()->getOrder();
            if( $oOrder && $oOrder->getId() )
            {
                Mage::getModel('exporter/exportorders')->exportOrders( array( $oOrder->getId() ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

Cronjob that exports multiple orders on schedule:

Edit:

```
app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Exporter/etc/config.xml

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <raveinfosys_exporter_cron>
            <schedule>
                <!-- Edit this to controller how often to export -->
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>raveinfosys_exporter/exportorders::checkForRejectedMessages</model>
            </run>
        </raveinfosys_exporter_cron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And add the following method in:

```
app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Exporter/Model/Exportorders.php

public function exportCronOrders()
{
    // Edit this date to correspond with the order timeframe.
    // There may be overlaps and you may need to add a flag to orders to indicate if they have already been exported.
    $sYesterday = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'yesterday' ) );
    $oOrders    = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' )->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter( 'created_at', array( 'gt'=> $sYesterday ) );
    $fileName = 'order_export_'.date("Ymd_His").'.csv';
    $fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$fileName, 'w');

    $this->writeHeadRow($fp);
    foreach ($oOrders as $oOrder) 
    {
        $this->writeOrder($oOrder, $fp);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that there is a typo error in the code for adding an observer to config.xml file:

line: 
    Raveninfosys_Exporter_Model_Observer
should be:
    Raveinfosys_Exporter_Model_Observer

i.e. is correct "Raveinfosys" and not "Raveninfosys"